Groupme API Has No Support for Topics
I would like to have bots that post in the topics beneath a group. For a user, these topics present as separate sub-groups. However, they seem to have no ID tied to them. Is there a parameter I can use in my /bots POST request that I can include to direct it to a specific topic?
Otherwise is there a unique identifier for a topic?
If not, is this not possible?
Was expecting to find any sort of docs or info on the "topic" objects in groupme but seem to find no mention.
